# How to fit a text in UILabel when the size is not proportionally

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

As per the title, how would I fit text into a UILabel when the width and height are not proportional?

In my application, the label has a width of 100, height of 500, and font size of 400. The result in the simulator is that the text is out of frame and cannot completely display on-screen. If I enable `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` the font is no longer 400, which is a requirement.

I know if the text does not scale proportionately it will look odd but that's not a problem for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to have the label be as large as it needs to be to contain the label, you can set it to larger than it needs to be in any circumstance and align it as necessary.

Another option is this:

```
label.text = newText;
CGRect bounds = label.bounds;
bounds.size = [newText sizeWithFont:label.font];
label.bounds = bounds;
```

Comment: thanks your reply but this code i have tried before,it will jus adjust the label size and able to contain the font(large),however the  thing i need is fix the label bounds size(small),and the font size(large)able to fit inside the label eventhough the font size are not proportionally

Comment: I guess I don't know what exactly you're looking for if not this and not an auto-sized font (which can be accomplished by checking "auto-size" in Interface Builder)